# SyntaxError: 'break' outside loop, error only given on raspberry pi 3, not on pc

Tags: python, raspberry-pi3

I have tried to use the equivalent of a do while loop in python. 
The raspberry Pi 3 I am using claims there is a syntax error.
edit: The raspberry runs python 2.7.13
edit 2: I am only using spaces for indentation

```py
while True: 
     input_var = raw_input(" printed text for choices 1 or 2 ")
     if (input_var == '1' or input_var == '2'):
         break    
     else: print"Error text"
```

The if statement is supposed be used to break out of the while True: loop, which it does on a laptop, but, when loaded on a raspberry pi 3, it throws the following error:

```
SyntaxError: 'break' outside loop
```

Comment: Check whether you don't have a mix of tabs and spaces for indentation; prefer only spaces for indentation.

Comment: (Also prefer to use Python 3 instead of 2, since Python 2 will not be supported anymore starting next year.)

Answer (score 0):

The error might come from the last print,
if your raspberry runs a python 3+ version.

try:

```
else:
    print("Error text")
```

Comment: I have already tried that method.
The raspberry runs python 2.7.12